# How to get access to the child in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>React Router class</h2>
        </div>
          <ul>
              <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/One">One</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/Two">Two</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/Three">Three</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/Four">Four</Link></li>
          </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import history from "./history";
import One from './One';
import Two from "./Two";
import Three from "./Three";
import Four from "./Four";
import Fourpointone from "./Fourpointone";
import NoMatch from "./NoMatch";





ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/One" component={One} />
            <Route path="/Two" component={Two} />
            <Route path="/Three" component={Three} />
            <Route path="/Four" component={Four}>
                <Route path="/Four/:id" component={Fourpointone}/>
            </Route>
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>



    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Four.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Four extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Four component</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/Four/123">Four Point One</Link></li>
                </ul>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Four;
```

Fourpointone.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Fourpointone extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is 4.1 component</h1>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Fourpointone;
```

Im learning about react router. I cant access to Foutpointone route path which is child of Four route path. I have "{this.props.children}" in Four.js which should access from parent to children but well... it's not working and I dont know why. How can I diplay Fourpointone component?
It seems like i cant use child route in parent route, so my child is ignored. Why? Its react 4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to render `Fourpointone` inside `Four`, you should just do it directly. You don't need to have all the `Route` components in one place with React Router 4. It could look like this:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Four extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Four component</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/Four/123">Four Point One</Link></li>
                </ul>
                <Route path="/Four/:id" component={Fourpointone}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Four;
```

Comment: There is no other way to nest child in parent in switch? I prefer not to mix Routes with Links.

Comment: the design behind react router has changed. In previous versions, you would just have your `routes.js` file and define all the routing related code there, as you would do for example in rails. Starting with v4, the idea is to treat the `Route` just as any other `React` component. So it is quite natural to mix it in.